# Rest - Error raised on Count items with filters in large list

Tags: list, rest

The solution proposed in the [linked thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139377/getting-an-itemcount-with-filtering-in-sp2013-using-rest-api?lq=1) does not seem to work for me as you can see below..

---

I have a rather huge list (2500 items) on SharePoint 2013 and I would like to get an idea of how many items that meets selected criterias, but I'm unable to get it working like i would like.

I know the itemcount endpoint, however that only returns the total amount of items in the list and I cannot seem to filter that.

I've tried this which I have found somewhere on this site:

```
_api/web/lists(guid'D38E6516-FB4F-4FCF-9E29-4FEC9CE06D2B')/Items/$count?&$filter=startswith(Title,'T757388')
```

But that only returns an error.

If I was dealing with a small list I would just make a normal Query and Count the items in the array, but the payload size exceeds the limit if I try this.

Anybody able to cast some light on this?

Comment: I have updated the post, the solution proposed does not seem to work for me...

Comment: Morten - I have changed the tittle since I think your problem is different and the fact you are working with a large list seems to be a mayor point in you issue. Until this is reopen I can't post a full answer... but I think it would be worth checking if you aren't hitting the list throttling limits. They should be at 5000 items by default, but remember that only means that the query can't at any point go over 5000 items... which means that smaller list can hit the limit also if SharePoint has to do some join to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks - while searching around for a solution I found out what I've done wrong. I then used the approach using ListData.svc and after some fiddling it worked out.

Here's the end result (HK is the list): /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/HK/$count?&$filter=((Updated_by_workflow eq false) and (Validated_by_manager eq false) and (Manager_Mail ne null) and (Employee_ID ne null))

Comment: Well, I will admit I still fail to see the root cause (outside of the theory I already explained) but I'm glad you have found an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to my issue (HK is the title of the list):

```
 /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/HK/$count?&$filter=((Updated_by_workflow eq false) and (Validated_by_manager eq false) and (Manager_Mail ne null) and (Employee_ID ne null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for a late answer but I hope someone steps into my code when dealing with more than 100,000 in a SharePoint list. It's good to mention that I gat some of the code on the web(Can't recall the author's name to quote him). Then modified it to use JavaScript Prototypes to Load the methods once when the page is refreshed to cope performance issues.

Here you go Morten:

`var HugeList = function() {
  this.altWeb = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/' || '';
  this.curWebsite = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
  this.completeUrl = this.curWebsite + '/sites/thewire/' || this.altWeb;
};`

`HugeList.prototype.replayCenter = function(listName) {
  var ItemCount = this.GetItemCount(this.completeUrl, listName);
  this.createRestUrl(this.completeUrl, ItemCount, listName);
};`

`HugeList.prototype.GetItemCount = function(siteurl, ListName) {
  var ItemCount = '';
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + ListName + "')/ItemCount",
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    headers: { Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose' }
  })
    .done(function(data) {
      ItemCount = data.d.ItemCount;
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  return ItemCount;
};`

`HugeList.prototype.createRestUrl = function(siteurl, ItemCount, ListName) {
  // prettier-ignore
  var listServiceUrl = this.completeUrl+ "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + ListName + "')/Items?$select=Title, BRANCH_DEPARTMENT, PHONE, COMPANY&$top=200";
  //Step 3: Rest call to procerss each items of list
  $.when(this.processList(listServiceUrl, ItemCount)).done(function() {});
};`

`HugeList.prototype.processList = function(nextUrl, ItemCount, gridID) {
  gridID = gridID || 'table_id';
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();`

`if (nextUrl == undefined) {
    dfd.resolve();
    return;
  }`

`this.getJSONDataFromUrl(nextUrl).done(
    function(listItems) {
      var items = listItems.d.results;`
      `var next = listItems.d.__next || '';`

```
  var indexAt = next.indexOf('_api');
  var resUrl = next.slice(indexAt);

  $.when(this.processList(this.completeUrl + resUrl, ItemCount)).done(
    function() {
      dfd.resolve();
    }
  );

  var tableHTML = '';
  var table = $('#' + gridID).DataTable();
  $.each(items, function(index, obj) {
    // prettier-ignore
    var phonenumber = obj.PHONE ? obj.PHONE : "-";
    // prettier-ignore
    tableHTML +="<tr><td>" + obj.Title + "</td><td>" +obj.BRANCH_DEPARTMENT 
    +"</td><td>" +phonenumber +"</td><td>" +obj.COMPANY +"</td></tr>";
  });
  table.rows.add($(tableHTML)).draw(); //Append each list row to data tabel
}.bind(this)
```

`); // Bind to HugeList context.
  return dfd.promise();`
};`

`HugeList.prototype.getJSONDataFromUrl = function(endpoint) {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
    }
  });
};`

`var largeList = new HugeList();
largeList.replayCenter('EmployeesList');`