# Item count with a filter condition using REST API gets result in web browser, error when coding

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to get the no.of items in a SharePoint list which satisfying a condition.

```
https://<SITEURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LISTNAME/$count?&$filter=FIELDNAME eq 'abc'
```

*using above url in browser gives me correct result.*

So I Tried get it using below code,

```
    getItems("/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LISTNAME/$count?&$filter=FIELDNAME eq 'abc'").done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
```

`getitems` function,

```
function getItems(url){

    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}
```

**But using this code gives an error *"415 Unsupported Media Type"***.
please help.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139377/getting-an-itemcount-with-filtering-in-sp2013-using-rest-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an ItemCount with filtering in SP2013 using REST api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139377/getting-an-itemcount-with-filtering-in-sp2013-using-rest-api)

Comment: @Yavuz I had seen that link, but that does not resolve my issue.

Comment: Wouldn't call this a duplicate, since that is about how to get the item count, and this is about an error received while trying to get an item count.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using the older endpoint instead of the newer one?

Comment: sorry I didn't know about the version diff, I got this Idea from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5db895ab-172b-424b-bd61-53de6db7fa33/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-how-to-get-the-item-count-with-startswith?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LISTNAME/$count?&$filter=FIELDNAME eq 'abc'
```

`_vti_bin` is the old (SP2007) SOAP WebServices endpoint (might still work),
But it is not the same as the Modern (SP2010) `_api` REST end point:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LISTNAME')/items?$filter=FIELDNAME eq 'abc'
```

You will get the resultst back in `data.d.results`, you can get the `length` of.

Comment: thanks, it worked. `_vti_bin` is working in web browser that confused me

Comment: It is supposed to work but the syntax is different. See the [jQuery / SPServices Library](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices), that uses the SOAP endpoint and sometimes still has greater powers than REST

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the result in done function you can use success and error methods. Your code look like

```
function getItems(url){

return $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    }
 success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I tried that one, but getting error

Comment: `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\r\n\"error\": {\r\n\"code\": \"\", \"message\": {\r\n\"lang\": \"en-US\", \"value\": \"Unsupported media type requested.\"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}","status":415,"statusText":"Unsupported Media Type"}`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the "Accept" header to "text/plain" when querying for counts from  "/_vti_bin/" URL via ajax.

```
function getItems(url){

  return $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "text/plain",
    }
  });
}
```