# SharePoint 2013 REST API ItemCount on / folder is 0

Tags: rest, folder, sharepoint-rest-api, item

When using the `ItemCount` function on the `/` folder, the count is 0.

The result of `GET /_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/')/ItemCount` is:

```
{
  "d": {
    "ItemCount": 0
  }
}
```

But the content is actually not empty as it contains all the system related files as well as the user created libraries.

I can't seem to find anything about this on google or the sharepoint api documentation.

Is there another way to get it? I know it's possible to count items in a library using the list functions, but a folder is not list.

Comment: Are you aware of that `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` returns items only and only if they are located at the very level specified inside the `('<level>')`? That means that your query would return the `ItemCount` of items at the `/`-level of your hierarchy, but not below that level.

Comment: good find, moe!

Comment: @moe Thanks for the answer! Yes, but there are items at the `/`-level, this is precisely what I'm trying to access. There are in reality 13 folders and 2 files that are returned at that level when not using the `ItemCount` function. That's why I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are facing a similar restriction as in this existing question: [Getting an ItemCount with filtering in SP2013 using REST api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139377/getting-an-itemcount-with-filtering-in-sp2013-using-rest-api).

To quote Vadim:

> "The ItemCount function could be applied to List resource [...] but not to ListItemCollection resource".

This same restriction would apply to `FileCollection resource` and `FolderCollection resource`, which - if I'm correct - the `/` level would represent either of.

`ItemCount`'s description is the following:

> Gets a value that specifies the count of items in the list folder.

This would mean, that a sub-directory (i.e. a type of `SP.Folder`) would be applicable

([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FolderCollection))

Note, that by using `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` can be returned items, so e.g. Folders would be excluded.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think `/` is indeed a `Collection`, it works with subfolders so I guess you're right. It is confirmed as well when trying to use the `ListItemAllFields` on `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/')` which is giving the following error: `The object specified does not belong to a list.`. So far, using `ItemCount` on other folders is giving the correct amount of files AND folders.